# What does the double backslash (\\) mean in URL?

Tags: uri

I'm learning network communication. Today I need to access files on a remote server in our local network, but in the first place I just typed the IP address. Instead of being asked for username and password, I could only get 403 error. My tutor pointed out that I omitted the preceding double backslash, and after I added it, things worked fine.

He didn't have time to explain all the details and left it to me. After some searching, I believe it has something to do with the URI specification, but I couldn't find what exactly the specification is and why the explorer would solve the input so differently.

Platform: both are Win 7 Enterprise Edition. I was working on IE 8.